# Memory registers puzzle

Tags: logic, puzzle

There are 3 memory registers: A, B and C. Following are the 3 valid commands:

1) copy from A to C

2) copy from B to C

3) Replace A by A - C

How can these commands be used to copy from B to A?

Comment: Hint: Swap two variables without using third variable.

Answer (score 0):

Copy $A$ to $C$

Replace $A$ by $A-C$ # A is now initialized to $0$

Copy $B$ to $C$

Replace $A$ by $A-C$ # $A$ now contains $-B$

Copy $A$ to $C$ # $C$ now contains $-B$

Replace $A$ by $A-C$ # A is now reinitialized to $0$

Replace $A$ by $A-C$ # $A$ now contains $B$

Comment: You've got it. Followup question: is that the fewest number of operations that will suffice?

Comment: No. I can do it in 3 moves.

Comment: Heh. You're not getting off that easily. Show us how that works.

Comment: I am working on it.

Comment: @RickDecker I thought I had a much better solution but I get bugs every time I try to cut out a line of code.I don't see the trick for a better solution.

Comment: Thanks John. This is very helpful.